# display none <tr> once a expiration date is met Javascript

Tags: javascript

working on a event listing, trying to make it not showing when the event passed.
The time is not really matter, just need the whole  not display when the date passed.

```js
$(function() {
   var currentDate = Date.now();
   $("tr.showAtDate").each(function() {
    var specifiedDateLimit = $(this).data('limit');
    if(!isNaN(date) && currentDate - date < 0) {
     $(this).show();
    }
   });
  });
```

```css
 .showAtDate { display: none; }
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="100%" class="table03">
    
  <tr class="showAtDate" data-limit="2015-01-28T01:00:00" >
  <td>December 12, 2018</td>
  <td><a  href="#" target="_blank">Event Name#1 - I pass already</a></td>
  <td>City, state</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="showAtDate" data-limit="2018-11-15T01:00:00" >
  <td>December 12, 2018</td>
  <td><a  href="#" target="_blank">Event Name#2 - not pass yet</a></td>
  <td>City, state</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="showAtDate" data-limit="2015-12-12T01:00:00" >
  <td>December 12, 2018</td>
  <td><a  href="#" target="_blank">Event Name#3 - not pass yet</a></td>
  <td>City, state</td>
  </tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: This seems like a perfect place to use momentjs. I don't advocate for many libraries, but anything that makes dates easier is great in my book. Especially when timezones become involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
var specifiedDateLimit = $(this).data('limit');
```

To:

```
var date = new Date($(this).data('limit'));
```

Now you're creating a Date object to compare with the current date.

You also need to hide the events in the past, like this:

```
if(!isNaN(date) && currentDate - date < 0) {
     $(this).show();
}
else {
    $(this).hide();
}
```